# How do you correctly format a destroy function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, destroy, kaboom

I am trying to use a destroy function in a game I am developing to create a platform that is destroyed upon contact with the player. However, when I run the game and touch the block, the game crashes. The block also destroys everything below it.

I tried using different variables to execute the function but the same problem occurred I tried many different methods, yielding the same results.

Here is my current code:

```
const configBlockEvents = (block) => {
  block.on("collide", (data) => {
    const __player = data[1];
    const __block = data[0];
    if(__block.t === "+") {
      nextLevel = true;
    }
    if(__block.t === "3") {
     destroy(__block)
    }
```

Comment: What is `destroy()`? That's not a standard JS function.

Comment: That makes sense, I tried to import a function from a Kaboom.js program. Thanks

Comment: Is there another operator that can help me in this instance?

Comment: JS is a garbage-collected language. Just remove all references to the object and it will be auto-deleted

Comment: I want it to exist until collision with the player.

Answer (score 0):

The Kaboom website has docs and demos for `destroy()`
https://kaboomjs.com/#destroy

```
// when the player collides with a game object with tag "fruit", remove the game object
player.onCollide("fruit", (fruit) => {
    destroy(fruit)
})
```

See the "RPG" demo
https://kaboomjs.com/play?demo=rpg

It looks like you're putting the collider on 'block' instead of your player.
And it might be better to use `onCollide()`.

It's best to post your full code or link to it